# Can I use a picture to fill in Tikz elements? How?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use a picture from the internet or from my computer to fill in the cube area. I need it to have a wooden texture. I've read something about tcolorbox and the tikz library, but it didn't help me any further.

This is the cube:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
            \draw[fill=brown] 
            (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=brown] 
            (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=brown] 
            (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The image would be: https://img.myloview.de/sticker/plywood-texture-with-gnarl-and-natural-wood-pattern-400-170218458.jpg

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: A real life saver, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `fill.image` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fill.image}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
            \draw[fill stretch image=Ikcfv.png] 
            (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill stretch image=Ikcfv.png] 
            (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill stretch image=Ikcfv.png] 
            (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Save the picture with some name (I used the name `wood.jpg`) in some folder and copy the path. Then try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% paste the path to the picture e.g 
\graphicspath{ {C:/images/tikz} }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \tikzset{
            wood/.style={%
                draw=black!10,
                path picture={%
                    \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
                        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{wood.jpg}};}}}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{1}
        \fill[wood]
        (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[wood]
        (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
        \fill[wood]
        (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw
        (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]